# Уникальный ID INTEGER - разграничение данных в таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

В MSSQL нужно сгенерировать уникальный ID в рамках запущенного скрипта, чтобы идентифицировать данные разных пользователей, сложенные в одну таблицу.

Скрипт может запускаться несколькими пользователями одновременно.
Один и тот же пользователь может запускать скрипт параллельно.
ID должен быть типа INTEGER.

Помогите, пожалуйста найти решение.
Есть идея использовать CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID(), но насколько это корректно?

Comment: Неясно. Если завтра тот же юзер будет работать - нумерация должна пойти заново или продолжиться? Юзер как идентифицируется - это отдельный логин, отдельная сессия, что-то ещё?

Comment: чтобы идентифицировать данные разных пользователей в одной таблице используют внешний ключ к таблице пользователей.

Comment: Если всё должно происходить в рамках одного запуска скрипта - пусть он вначале сгенерит себе GUID и им себя идентифицирует.